# Confusing DE concept question

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

This is the question:

A reduced copy of a painting by Kandinsky is placed on the top of original. Is there a point of the painting covered by a point of the copy which has the same color? If it is placed upside-down?

I'm completely lost at how to answer this problem.  Anyone know?  Thanks.

Comment: Define "reduced".

Comment: Reduced in size maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment above, I take it to mean that '*reduced copy*'stands for '*reduced in size but geometrically similar (excluding reflections).*'

If that is the case, consider applying some fixed point theorem (e.g., Brouwer's) to show that *some* point on the reduced copy *does* sit precisely above the analogous ("*same color*") point on the original painting.

The map on which the theorem must be applied is $f:D \to D$, where $D\subset\mathbf{R}^2$ is the rectangular domain occupied by the original painting and, for every point $x \in D$ on the original painting, $f(x) \in D$ is the analogous point on the reduced painting. You're in business *if* you can show that $f$ is continuous. I'll leave that to you, but here's a hint: view the map as the composition of a scaling by some constant &, possibly, a rotation & a translation. (This also helps answer the second part of the problem.)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for not responding earlier!